# Rails 4 proper way to prevent wrong user creating likes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to find this on google but can't seem to find anything on this. I have a model called Likes, along with a controller which simply belongs to an Event and a User. I would like to prevent people from creating a Like when they're not logged in, and not allow them to create a like for another user. What is the proper way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: You mean, like checking `current_user`?

Comment: Yes, how could I do that in the model?

Comment: It's possible, but it's bad style. Do it in controller.

Comment: why is doing it in the model bad style?

Comment: Because current_user is not model's concern. It's a part of current session. And sessions are business of controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a user based system, all queries related to user-owned data need to include the user, or originate from it.  Most authentication systems have a helper to get the current user, often called `current_user`.

Assuming some things about your model, for "liking" an event, you could do it a couple ways:

```
current_user.likes.create(event_id: params[:event_id])
Like.create(event_id: params[:event_id], user: current_user)
```

Validations can help as well, making sure event and user IDs are always present.  If no user is logged in, this should make it fail, assuming someone guessed the path to try and manually create a like.

Comment: that makes sense. what if the user is not logged in though? how could i handle that in the controller?

Comment: Have you looked at any authentication frameworks?  Take [a look at devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers), for example.  In devise, you would add a `before_filter` to force authentication before accessing any controller method you want to make sure has a `current_user`.  So without a logged in user, the method will simply never get hit so you don't need to worry about it.